# How can I change to pivot point of Blender raote vector node?

Tags: vector, vector-mapping

I'm currently making my wavy grass and trying to figure out how to rotate the grass texture in 4x4 tiles
now i'm looking for how to change the pivote point of rotate vector node to the bottom center of each grass tiles

[image: Vector nodes]

[image]